# How to draw chart in excel with age and its count

Tags: excel, xlsx

I have create a chart with age and its count in excel. How can I count the number of people in age 1,2,3,4..14.

```
Age
4
3
10
8
2
5
5
4
6
2
1
8
4
9
5
8
12
8
4
10
1
7
8
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by in age 1...14? 
To what I understand, you can use countif function.
A possible answer for your question can be seen [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VE4KVnm2w_Pg-3L8BaIAYlspfYFuDYzDr7Dzhp9JmUo/edit?usp=sharing)

Clear instruction and syntax can be seen [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

I will summarise: 
So you this is the function countif (`range`,`criteria`). 
`range` indicates the ranges of excel fields you will count 
`criteria` indicates the rules of the fields. 
For example =countif (A1:A3,"apple"). The function will count from field A1 to field A3. If the field has value of "apple" it will be counted.

Comment: Yes I want this .Thank you , how can I achieve this ? Please explain .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 or more different ways:
1. By adding pivot table with age on row and count of age in values.(most easy)
2. Assuming you data is on column am you can set  14 cells with values 1 to 4 on lets say column c (from c1 to c14) and on d1 enter:

`=countif(a:a,c1)`

and drag this to the until row 14.

Answer (score 0):

@user41048, as said by Balinti, you can certainly use COUNTIF or a PIVOT table. 
Say for example you need to find number of people in the age group of 20, 
All you have to do is, Select the cell you want to enter the formula and type this, 
=COUNTIF(Data Range, Criteria)

Where Data range is the range of cells, 
criteria is the age you want to count for?

However for a better understanding on how you can use COUNTIF, 
Please Refer to the below link.

http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/11/12/using-countif-sumif-excel-help/